# variable and it's parent scope inside ng-if

Tags: angularjs

According to some links i read "Unlike ng-show the ng-if directive creates a new scope. "  But i am confused about below scenario. See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGUScRISJ1sKOdHxiEEY?p=preview)

```
<div ng-if="true">
      <div>
          visibility variable: {{showIt}}<br>
          visibility variable: {{$parent.showIt}}
      </div>
      
          <a href="" ng-show="!showIt" ng-click="$parent.showIt = true">Show It</a><br>
          <a href="" ng-show="!$parent.showIt" ng-click="$parent.showIt = true">Show It</a>
     
      <div ng-show="showIt">
        This is a dynamically-shown div.
        <a href="" ng-click="hideIt()">Hide it</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

In the above example both {{showIt}} and {{$parent.showIt}} will evaluate to same value and even the ng-sho will evaluate to same values. But in the ng-click if i dont specify parent then it will give unexpected result as ng-if creates child scope. I also checked that while using ng-model parent scope needs to be used. So why does  {{showIt}} and {{$parent.showIt}} will evaluate to same?

what care i should take when using ng-if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-if` does create a new scope, but it is not an **isolate scope**, so it inherits prototypically from the parent.

However, a caveat of prototypal inheritance is that setting a primitive value on the child scope shadows the value on the parent scope, which is why you need to explicitly set `$parent.showIt` rather than just `showIt` in your `ng-click`.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/sxkzzjfp/

**Example 1**: `child.showIt` initially refers to `parent.showIt`. Try clicking "toggle parent" a few times, and you will see that the values are in sync. Executing `showIt = !showIt` causes the child and parent values to become decoupled, since the child value shadows the parent value.

**Example 2**: this workaround is recommended by Angular. Instead of setting primitive values directly on the scope, set them on an object instead. Executing `config.show = true` first looks up the prototype chain for the `config` object on the parent scope, and then sets a property of that object. In this example, the child and parent values are always in sync.

Answer (score 1):

$scope.showIt present inside your child scope and child scope can have access on Parent controller that is the only reason behind populating the same value

whenver you using some $scope variable of child ,If variable present inside child controller then it show result accordin to child value but if variable is not present inside child controller angular will search that variable in parent controller {not in grand parent controller }

For example:-

```
angulare.controller('parent',function($scope){
$scope.parent="hello its me Parent";
});

angular.controller('child',function($scope){
console.log($scope.parent);//it will retrn parent value
})
```